# Is there a trick to git log --follow a directory which has been renamed?

Tags: git

The git command has a useful command to follow a file after a rename, as in `git log --follow path/to/some/file`. Unfortunately, it works only for an individual file. I'd like to be able to do the equivalent of `git log --follow some/directory`.

One way of doing this would probably be to massage the output of `git ls-tree` and do that in a loop, but the problem then becomes that commits affecting multiple files won't be "coalesced" into one commit.

Is there a better way to do it? Note: using git 2.7.4

Comment: Good question. Have you found any answers yet?

Answer (score 10):

No.

Git does not store directories, only files.  When you use any path name to commands like `git log` or `git diff` that look at entire commits, Git essentially says "start with the whole commit, then shrink it down to file(s) matching that path".  Directories here simply wind up selecting every file *in* the directory.

The `--follow` option can only follow one file.  So if you could somehow manage to get it to apply to a directory, Git would first turn the directory into a set of files, then pick one of those files and follow just that one.

(The actual `--follow` code is terribly hacky.  It leverages off the rename detection code, but only works when commits are being compared in the newer-to-older order: if you add `--reverse`, `--follow` never works at all.  Probably the whole thing needs to be thrown out and re-coded.  Perhaps by re-coding it, you could make it handle multiple file names, and even directories full of files.)

Comment: I know that only files are stored; I thought that maybe someone has worked out a solution, even hackish... Who knows :)

Comment: Is there a bug opened somewhere with this issue?

Comment: @JérômePouiller: Git doesn't use any of the usual issue tracking software. You could file a bug report if you like, but if you search through the Git mailing list archives, you'll see that the fact that `--follow` is a hack crop up numerous times. Nobody has managed to come up with a satisfactory rewrite yet....

Comment: `git log --follow` works with a directory without any problem, simplest example: `git log --follow .` and I get git log pertaining to all files in the current dir (git version 2.25.1). Similarly the pathspec option works `git log -- ...`

Comment: @bloody: directories are never renamed; the `--follow` option is a no-op for this case.

Comment: OK I missed renaming aspect in op's question, sorry. However it is not 'no-op', it generates log following included files - it has the path meaning, not a dir-object. I recommend, potentially useful :)

Comment: @bloody: you get the same thing with `git log -- <dir>` as you do with `git log --follow -- <dir>`. That's what I mean by no-op here: it has no effect on actual behavior. It *should*, if Git could detect a directory rename, but it won't until Git can detect a directory rename. :-)

Comment: Right, I stated myself that the same as `git log --` with a dir. Yea, it depends on relative to what we consider something to be "no-op", let it be, I can get that :)

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a builtin way to do this.

One can do this using a script and following a simple algorithm:

- For each file generate a list of commits associated with it
- Combine all the lists and do a stable sort on them (this is tricky because determining ordering of commits isn't straightforward)
- Iteratively execute git log for each of the commits and pipe it all through less

Here's a hacky way to do it using python 3 and the `sh` module, won't work on Windows for various reasons.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shlex
import sys
import tempfile

import sh

def _get_commits(fname):
    # Ask for the commit and the timestamp
    # .. the timestamp doesn't guarantee ordering, but good enough
    for c in sh.git('log', '--follow', '--pretty=%ct %h', fname,
                   _tty_out=False, _iter=True):
        c = c.strip().split()
        yield int(c[0]), c[1]

def git_log_follow_multi(filenames):
    if len(filenames) == 0:
        print("Specify at least one file to log")
    elif len(filenames) <= 1:
        os.system('git log --follow -p %s' % filenames[0])
    else:
        # Use git log to generate lists of commits for each file, sort
        commits = []
        for fname in filenames:
            commits += _get_commits(fname)

        # Sort the lists (python's sort is stable)
        commits.sort(reverse=True)

        # Uniquify (http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark)
        seen = set()
        seen_add = seen.add
        commits = [c for c in commits if not (c in seen or seen_add(c))]

        # Finally, display them
        tname = None

        try:
            file_list = ' '.join(shlex.quote(fname) for fname in filenames)

            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as fp:
                tname = fp.name
                for _, commit in commits:
                    fp.write('git log -p -1 --color %s %s\n' % (commit, file_list))

            # Use os.system to make our lives easier
            os.system('bash %s | less -FRX' % tname)
        finally:
            if tname:
                os.unlink(tname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    git_log_follow_multi(sys.argv[1:])
```

Now, this script doesn't exactly meet your needs since it takes a list of files, but you can execute it using a glob and it'll do what you're looking for.

```
./script.py src/*
```

Answer (score 0):

[As torek mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871146/4051245), `git diff --follow` tracks renames but only works on a single file. Throwing together a couple of commands in Bash (or Git Bash on Windows) yields the combined result for all files contained in a directory:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f \
  -exec git log --oneline --follow '{}' \; \
  | cut -d ' ' -f 1 \
  | sort --unique > /tmp/commits ; \
git log --oneline \
  | cut -d ' ' -f 1 \
  | grep -F -f /tmp/commits \
  | xargs -I {} git --no-pager show {} --no-patch ; \
rm /tmp/commits
```

1. `find /path/to/directory -type f` finds all files below the selected directory.

   This can be tuned, e. g., `-maxdepth 1` excludes files in subdirectories and `! -name '*.bin'` excludes certain files.
2. `-exec git log --oneline --follow '{}' \;` executes `git log` on all found files, following each file across renames.
3. `cut -d ' ' -f 1` extracts the commit hashes.
4. `sort --unique > /tmp/commits` removes duplicates (and sorts the hashes alphanumerically). The result is stored in a temporary file.
5. `git log --oneline` gets the full log *in the right order*.
6. `cut -d ' ' -f 1` extracts the commit hashes.
7. `grep -F -f /tmp/commits` extracts those entries that affect the files we're interested in. They are now in the right order.
8. `xargs -I {} git --no-pager show {} --no-patch` shows the commit details.

   This can be tuned, e. g., remove `--no-patch` to see what changed or use `--format=short` to format the output.
9. `rm /tmp/commits` removes the temporary file again.